i experience this error when making build after installing react-native-mmkv
⚠️  Something went wrong running pod install in the ios directory.
Command pod install failed.
└─ Cause: Error installing MMKVCore
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/Tencent/MMKV.git /var/folders/v6/8yrsb82d0j1ckkc8dccwm70c0000gn/T/d20240711-4366-2smlq1 --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v1.3.7
Cloning into '/var/folders/v6/8yrsb82d0j1ckkc8dccwm70c0000gn/T/d20240711-4366-2smlq1'...
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 3689 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
I installed react-native-mmkv on expo,did the prebuild but when i run npx expo run:ios i get the error aboveenter image description here

Same issue. Did you find any solution to this issue?

Same - I have been on airplane wifi however, so I'm suspecting that could be a factor.
